# Javascript in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I'd like to use some Javascript on my wiki pages, but I haven't been able to figure out how. I'm using a hosted solution on [Wikia](http://wikia.com). So I am unable to modify the installation, add extensions or hack the settings. But I have admin rights on my wiki so I can access the `MediaWiki` namespace and `MediaWiki:Common.js`.

The javascript I want to use ([Tangle](http://worrydream.com/Tangle/)) will consist of an external script that will be common to a number of pages(but not all pages in the wiki) and some code that will be specific to each page, the kind you would normally put inline in the `<script>` tag.

The trouble is, Mediawiki sanitizes `<script>` tags, and I haven't been able to find a way to put them in. I'm trying to make this into an editor-friendly setup that will be used across the wiki, so I'm also trying to avoid hacks and find a proper solution.

---

#### Update: New problem

Apparently MediaWiki also sanitizes the HTML5 data attributes, which Tangle relies on heavily. Any ideas on solving that problem is very welcome.

Comment: I would split the "new problem" out of this question and ask it as a separate question so that each maintains its own focus. There's probably some approaches you can use other than HTML5 data attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MediaWiki doesn't allow `<script>` tags in pages for obvious reasons: if it did, anyone could use them to inject JavaScript into your wiki and e.g. steal login credentials.

There are a couple of things you *could* do:

- Write some generic JavaScript code to extract the parameters from something that *is* allowed on MediaWiki pages, such as a hidden `<div>`.  Be careful not to introduce security holes when doing that.
- Add something like this to MediaWiki:Common.js:

  ```
  importScript('MediaWiki:Tangle/' + wgPageName + '.js');
  ```

  Then, whenever a user visits the page "Foo", the page "MediaWiki:Tangle/Foo.js" will be loaded as JavaScript.  Of course, that page will only be editable by admins, but that might still be enough for your needs.  (You could use the same trick to import JS from pages in other namespaces, but that would open a security hole miles wide.)

Comment: This could work but apparently MediaWiki also sanitizes the HTML5 data attributes, which Tangle relies on heavily. Any ideas on how to circumvent that?

Comment: HTML5 data attributes [should be allowed by MediaWiki](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26247), if you're running version 1.17 (or later) and haven't set [`$wgHtml5`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgHtml5) to false.  If that's not the case, please report it as a bug.

Comment: Hmm, as I said, I'm running on Wikia, a hosted solution. Maybe I should ask them. Thanks.

Comment: Wikia is [apparently](http://www.wikia.com/Special:Version) still running MediaWiki 1.16.5.  They do seem to be running in HTML5 mode, so just upgrading to MW 1.17 should do the trick.  You might suggest that to them, although [this page](http://community.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:User_javascript_not_working) claims that Wikia is planning to skip MW 1.17 entirely and just go straight to 1.18 when it comes out.

Comment: Ok, I guess that blows my plans a bit. Thanks for the extensive information. Any suggestions on an alternate hosted wiki?

Comment: Not really, though you can [find some on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+mediawiki+hosting).  As I noted [in another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53317/9602), with free hosting you often get what you pay for; if you're at all serious about your wiki, I'd suggest at least considering paid hosting options (either paid MediaWiki hosting or generic web hosting on which you can set up your own MediaWiki installation) too.

Comment: I couldn't say I'm very serious about this one, it's just a hobby thing and as I see it now, MediaWiki is way too complex for my taste. Thinking of using [gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) for the lack of a simpler and cleaner alternative.